# Why compiler throws the error Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

The following function is to be done using this code snippet.

```
    ' If [b9] = "#N/A" Then
    ' If Range("B9").Value = "#N/A" Then
    ' If Range("B9") = #N/A Then
    Range("A9").Select
    With Selection.Interior
    .Color = -16776961
    End With
```

If the value in the cell B9 has #N/A then the cell A9 must be made red in colour.

The first three lines are the syntaxes that I have tried. None of them seem to work and the error `Type Mismatch` comes.

Comment: `If ISNA(range("a9"))...` and no need to select.

Comment: @SJR sorry i am unable to understand what you meant

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?r=SearchResults&s=1|270.3019 and see BigBen's answer.

Comment: You could do it with _Conditional Formatting_ - no `VBA` required.  Add `=ISNA($B$9)` to cell `A9` Conditional Formatting using _Use a formula to determine which cells to format_.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Range("B9").Value) Then
    Range("A9").Interior.Color = -16776961
End If
```

Comment: was about to post that as a single line!  I tend to use Application, rather than WorkSheetFunction... does the error handling for each make a significant difference?

Comment: @Cyril haha I thought about single line but personally prefer multi-line syntax, still yeah an easy solution. `Application` would be just fine as well, maybe preferable to `WorksheetFunction` depending on what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter than of BigBen's answer:

```
If [ISNA(B9)] Then...
```